# XNA - Scale Direction Vector3

Tags: c#, vector, xna

I have a small space shooter where I have turrets shooting at my fighter.

The turrets fire a projectile at my fighter using this simple math:

```
Vector3 destination = mTarget;
Vector3 origin = mPosition;
Movement = destination - origin;
Movement .Normalize();
mPosition += Movement * speed;
```

now this works fine, the projectile fires at my fighter.

**HOWEVER** - the projectile then stops once it hits the position the fighter was at when the turret shot that projectile - basically, I want the projectile to keep moving along its direction vector regardless if its passed the point the ship was on.

I have tried scaling/multiplying the direction the vector moves in, but nothings working. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the code of the you "scaling/multiplying the direction the vector moves in"

Comment: Hey Lemur! I just fixed my problem - some slight restructure got it working :D

Comment: Add your own answer and except it, that will help you get more rep and people won't still answer it, and include your code in case others are interested

Answer (score 0):

Change your ending condition...

```
 // by distance

 float distance = (destination - origin).Length();

 distance *= 1.1; // Will overpassed by 10%
 ...

 mPosition += Movement * Speed;
 distance -= Speed;             // Movement lenght is one
 if (distance<0) destroy_bullet();


 // by position
 mPosition += Movement * Speed;
 if (!Screen.Bounds.Contains(mPosition)) destroy_bullet();
```